# Wamp server localhost error

Tags: wampserver

All my services of `WAMP` server are running, but when I opened my `http://localhost/` it gives me this error

"HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because listing directory contents is disabled. Something like this can be found in the apache config file `httpd.conf`:

```
Options -Indexes
```

The *reason* you're seeing this is probably because of one of two reasons:

1. You haven't got an index page (index.php or index.html usually)
2. You have got an index page but your settings are incorrect

Check your apache config for something like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Your directory index should list the name(s) of the file(s) that you want to use as the index page. Cross reference the two and you should be able to get it working.

Finally, make sure you always run `httpd -t` to test your apache configuration after making changes, prior to restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the content of c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf  file to the following.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And Restart your Apache server after making these changes.